# No search APIs in ehcache 3?

Tags: ehcache

I am trying the new ehcache version but I noticed that, apparently, there are no search APIs.

Is this normal or am I missing something? Documentation says nothing about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is that searching in a cache has very strange semantics in the face of expiry and eviction. Since Ehcache 3 is focusing on what it is good at - the caching use case - we decided to shave some features that are more targeted at the storage use case.